# Incompatible pointer types sending 'Class' to parameter of type 'id<NSCopying>'

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, nscopying

I have updated xcode and now I get the error message
Incompatible pointer types sending 'Class' to parameter of type 'id'

```
- (void)mapObjectClass:(Class)objectClass toCellClass:(Class)cellClass {
  [self.objectToCellMap setObject:cellClass forKey:objectClass];
}
```

I would really appreciate it if someone can shed some light on this issue im having and how I can resolve it.

Comment: from my understanding, id is the equivalent to a void *. Class isn't a pointer, therefore, not compatible with id. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. :)

Comment: Hi Simon, thank you for your prompt response, so what do you suggest I change it to?

Comment: @SimonGermain is not quite correct. id is a generic type meaning an Objective-C object of any class. Class objects are indeed objects and can be sent to methods expecting id arguments. The problem is rmaddy describes in his answer.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I wasn't 100% sure :)

Comment: thank you Simon and Andrew, changing id to Class solved the issue :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keys for an NSDictionary must be objects that adhere to the **NSCopying** protocol. **Class** doesn't qualify.

The first question is why are your method parameters of type **Class** and not something more typical such as a specific class type (object pointer) or **id**?